# инициализация unordered_map

Tags: c++, map

Было вот такое и работало: `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> x = {..};`, сейчас пытаюсь переделать на `std::unordered_map<const char*, const char*, decltype(hash_func), decltype(comp_func)> x(0, hash_func, comp_func) = {..}` дальше синтакс ошибка. Или может получится функции засунуть прямо в <>template?

```
auto hash_func = [](const char* x) { return (size_t)*x; };
auto comp_func = [](const char* x, const char* y) { return !strcmp(x, y); };
```

Comment: Покажите сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: типичная куча `syntax error: missing ';' before '=' syntax error: missing ';' before '{' syntax error: '='` из которой ничего непонятно что не так=)

Comment: @. Doe А также покажите, как у вас определены hash_func и comp_func

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы используете неправильный синтаксис.
Вы уже вызвали конструктор

```
std::unordered_map<const char*, const char*, decltype(hash_func), decltype(comp_func)> 
x(0, hash_func, comp_func) = { /*...*/ };
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Поэтому что-либо добавлять в эту строку нельзя.

Просто поставьте точку с запятой после круглых скобок, как того просит компилятор.

```
std::unordered_map<const char*, const char*, decltype(hash_func), decltype(comp_func)> 
x(0, hash_func, comp_func);
                         ^^^
```

Для создания объекта может быть вызван только один конструктор класса, если не считать делегирования конструкторов.:)

Comment: с хвостом то что делать? может позже добавить x.hash_func = hash_func.. ответ что нельзя такое сделать или нет?)

Comment: @J.Doe Зачем вам хвост?:) Вы уже указали в скобках, что используете hash_func и comp_func. Вы уже передали их в качестве аргументов конструктору.:)

Comment: там в {} список инициализции очень длинный, если вручную через for загонять потом некрасиво, т.е мне нужно еще передать ему аргументов

Comment: @J.Doe Вы должны выбирать какой-то один конструктор. Нельзя сразу же два конструктора выбрать одновременно.